# Java implementing Queue by extending LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, extends

I've been trying to research a way to implement a Queue using a LinkedList.  I've mostly found examples showing me how to do it by literally using "implements"  in the class.  **BUT** What I'd like to do, however, is to **extend the LinkedList** class.  For example I have written something like this:

```
public class TestQueue extends LinkedList{

    public TestQueue(){

    }

    public void enqueue(ObjectType c){

       add(c);
    }

    public Object dequeue(){
       return (ObjectType ) remove();
    }

    // more code for peek and size ect....


}
```

Is this really all I have to do to use a linked-list type queue?  How then would I have to set a head(front) and a tail(rear) to use the linked list just like a queue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably `Queue` is an interface and your class should implement this interface and also extend from `LinkedList` class.

Comment: A [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is already a Queue! In fact, it is even a double-ended queue or Deque. Is there a reason why you are trying to create your own implementation on top of the list?

Comment: @andersschuller probably OP's implementing his/her own `LinkedList` class.

Comment: @andersschuller I'm just trying to learn about how to use queues in a linked list and this method was suggested to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding and looking up the LinkedList class, you should be good to go as the only thing you should need is the Queue class, which LinkedList already includes. I would recommend taking a quick look at these resources however just to make sure your understanding is where you want it to be.

API from Oracle - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Learning about Queues & Staks (Document) - http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/43stack/

Comment: oh wow...my professor did not make that very clear.  Thank you for the helpful links

Comment: Happy to help, if you have any specific questions on those feel free to ask and I'll do my best to answer anything particular you might not understand.

Comment: then, how would I set the head(front) and tail(rear) to use this linked list as a queue?  Do i have to make my own setNext() and whatnot?

Comment: If I am understanding the question correctly, all you have to do is whenever they change (e.g. you add a new item or remove one) you just have to keep track of which was last added or which is next to be removed. I generally do this using variables on the class itself, for example in your case, just put two private variables on your TestQueue class, one marking the head and one for the tail. Update them accordingly.